# Check the render method of CartItem

Tags: javascript, react-native

Hi there I am trying to follow tutorial but it gives this check render method error. I am making Cart for shopping app

Here is CartScreen:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, FlatList, Button, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

import Colors from '../../constants/Colors';
import CartItem from '../../components/shop/CartItem';

const CartScreen = props => {
  const cartTotalAmount = useSelector(state => state.cart.totalAmount);
  const cartItems = useSelector(state => {
    const transformedCartItems = [];
    for (const key in state.cart.items) {
      transformedCartItems.push({
        productId: key,
        productTitle: state.cart.items[key].productTitle,
        productPrice: state.cart.items[key].productPrice,
        quantity: state.cart.items[key].quantity,
        sum: state.cart.items[key].sum
      });
    }
    return transformedCartItems;
  });

  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <View style={styles.summary}>
        <Text style={styles.summaryText}>
          Total:{' '}
          <Text style={styles.amount}>${cartTotalAmount.toFixed(2)}</Text>
        </Text>
        <Button
          color={Colors.accent}
          title="Order Now"
          disabled={cartItems.length === 0}
        />
      </View>
      <FlatList data={cartItems}
       keyExtractor={item => item.productId}
       renderItem={itemData => ( 
       <CartItem 
        quantity={itemData.item.quantity} 
        title={itemData.item.productTitle}
        amount={itemData.item.sum}
        onRemove={() => {}}
        />
        )}
        />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen: {
    margin: 20
  },
  summary: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    marginBottom: 20,
    padding: 10,
    shadowColor: 'black',
    shadowOpacity: 0.26,
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
    shadowRadius: 8,
    elevation: 5,
    borderRadius: 10,
    backgroundColor: 'white'
  },
  summaryText: {
    fontSize: 18
  },
  amount: {
    color: Colors.primary
  }
});

export default CartScreen;
```

And Here is my CartItem Component :

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Platform
} from 'react-native';
import { Ionicons } from 'react-native-vector-icons';

const CartItem = props => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.cartItem}>
      <View style={styles.itemData}>
        <Text style={styles.quantity}>{props.quantity} </Text>
        <Text style={styles.mainText}>{props.title}</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.itemData}>
        <Text style={styles.mainText}>${props.amount.toFixed(2)}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.onRemove} style={styles.deleteButton}>
          <Ionicons
            name={'ios-trash'}
            size={23}
            color="red"
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  cartItem: {
    padding: 10,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    marginHorizontal: 20
  },
  itemData: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  quantity: {
    color: '#888',
    fontSize: 16
  },
  mainText: {
    fontSize: 16
  },
  deleteButton: {
    marginLeft: 20
  }
});

export default CartItem;
```

I have copy paste the component inside the cart screen it works but as a component it does not work what should I do ?
What could be wrong here ?

[Image of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x54CA.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try to change the way import your icons
`import { Ionicons } from 'react-native-vector-icons';`

It should be

`import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'`

Comment: wow it really worked it is interesting that it doesnt give error about it

Comment: but I cannot see the title of the product do you have any idea about that ? Only price is there

Comment: Please share me abour your original data. You can console.log the data before render it